# Is it possible to install Ubuntu on a Microsoft Surface (RT)?

Tags: system-installation

I want to know if it's possible to install Ubuntu on a Microsoft Surface tablet (with Windows RT).

Please help me. I want to know because you can't install any desktop apps on it.