# How do I put Ubuntu onto USB?

Tags: 12.04, usb, surface

I have a Surface RT (32GB), and I want to run ubuntu on it from a usb. What do I put on the USB to run this? Where do I get it?

Comment: Related: http://askubuntu.com/questions/320870/is-it-possible-to-install-ubuntu-on-a-microsoft-surface

Surface RT is ARM, and Ubuntu doesn't

Comment: You need to create a presistent USB.  Take a look at [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator), it might help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Universal USB installer to do this job. You can download it from[Universal USB installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)